# Flash AS3 Security Sandbox Violation / s.ytimg.com

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been reading about this trouble for days now and i'm going mad. Please Help!

I'm trying to load in vain a YouTube video into my portfolio. I'v uploaded the video on Youtube and it's Public. 
I've tried the code with a bunch of other Youtube videos and it works perfect with them all except with mine...
Like i said i'm going MAD!!! please help!!

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://s.ytimg.com/crossdomain.xml' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///M|/Architecture/PORTFOLIO/WEB/PORTFOLIO.swf'

Here's the code of the part in context:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import flash.ui.MouseCursor;
import flash.system.Security;

pages.visible = false;
pages.fullPage.alpha = 0;
var my_images:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;

var page_no:Number = 1;
pages.pb.alpha = 0;

pages.btnBallon.visible = false;
pages.btnBallon.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lVid);
pages.btnBallon.buttonMode = false;

//Youtube loader

Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
Security.allowDomain("youtube.com");
Security.allowDomain("s.ytimg.com");
Security.allowDomain("i1.ytimg.com");
Security.allowDomain("i.ytimg.com");
Security.allowDomain("http://s.ytimg.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.allowDomain("popslinger.org");
Security.allowDomain("http://www.box.net/api/crossdomain.xml");

Security.loadPolicyFile("http://i.ytimg.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://s.ytimg.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile('http://youtube.com/crossdomain.xml');
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.box.net/api/crossdomain.xml");



function video():void{
pages.btnBallon.visible = true;
pages.btnBallon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lVid);
pages.btnBallon.buttonMode = true;
}

function lVid(e:Event = null):void{

loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
}

function onInit(e:Event):void{
addChild(loader);
player = loader.content;
player.addEventListener("onReady",onPlayerReady);
}

function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
var pageTween:Tween = new Tween(pages.fullPage, "alpha",     Strong.easeOut,pages.fullPage.alpha, 0, 1, true);
player.setSize = (560,315);
player.x = pages.x + 120;
player.y = pages.y;
pages.visible = false;
pages.btnBallon.visible = false;
pages.btnBallon.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lVid);
pages.btnBallon.buttonMode = false;
/*pages.btnNext.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextPage);
pages.btnNext.visible = false;
pages.btnPrev.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextPage);
pages.btnPrev.visible = false;*/
player.loadVideoByUrl("www.youtube.com/embed/omcl93EYTrM",0);
//player.loadVideoById("omcl93EYTrM",0);    

}
```

Comment: Are you compiling to web??

Comment: If i publish to SWF and Restrict the access to local only everything works except the video and if i switch it to HTML and set it to network nothing loads..

You think when I'll publish it on the domain and put the access to network only it would work?

Answer (score 1):

Try change this value:

File -> Publish settings

[image: Sandbox_flash]

Comment: Hi yes i did... If i publish to SWF and Restrict the access to local only everything works except the video and if i switch it to HTML and set it to network nothing loads (the funny part is that if i choose an other random video on youtube it works Perfectly.. You think when I'll publish it on the domain and put the access to network only it would work?

Comment: When you publish it on domain all works and maybe if you still with problems, you can change the relative references to absolute references i.e. change /yourFolder/yourFile.ext to http : //domain/yourFolder/yourFile.ext. The option will be use a variable prefix to all your paths.